# Does NDP (Neighbor Discovery Protocol) reduce ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) attacks?

Tags: network, attacks, attack-prevention, arp-spoofing

I read the [comparison of NDP with ARP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-3000/chapter1-41/index.html) but am uncertain if NDP does reduce any amounts of ARP attacks, given that with NDP, ARP is not used for address resolution.

For the discussion to be specific, let us leave out the extension of NDP, SEND (Secure Network Discovery protocol).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to typical ARP usage under IPv4 is the ND address resolution function, which is used when a host wants to transmit to an on-link prefix but doesn't yet know the layer two address of the destination host.
The sending host multicasts a neighbor solicitation, and the destination host, if reachable, responds with a neighbor advertisement containing its layer two address.

as in ARP, these exchanges are **unsecured.**, but with The Secure Neighbor Discovery (SEND) Protocol prevents an attacker who has access to the broadcast segment from abusing NDP or ARP to trick hosts into sending the attacker traffic destined for someone else 'ARP poisoning'.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/969831/why-is-arp-replaced-by-ndp-in-ipv6) for more explanation.